# Zend Router - URL with or without parameters are two differents routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I'm currently creating a new version of my website using Zend Framework and I'm stuck with a little problem I've seen in the past.

There are my routes: (a part)

```php
// BLOG -> CATEGORIES
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'blog/categories',
    array(
        'module'     => 'blog',
        'controller' => 'categories',
        'action'     => 'index'
    )
);
$router->addRoute('blog-categories', $route);

// BLOG -> CATEGORIES -> LIST ARTICLES (:alias = name of the category)
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'blog/categories/:alias',
    array(
        'module'     => 'blog',
        'controller' => 'categories',
        'action'     => 'list',
        'alias'      => null
    )
);
$router->addRoute('blog-categories-list', $route);
```

The problem is that: when I go to `/blog/categories/`, it brings me the `list` action. What I don't want. I need the `index`.

Is there a way to fix that without using, for exemple, `/blog/categories/view/:alias` ?

Note: I have the same problem for `/blog/` (list all articles) and `/blog/:alias/` (display single article).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By including `'alias' => null` you're specifying a default value for the `:alias` parameter, used if it is not in the URL. This is why your second route is always matching. Remove this and it should work as you are wanting it to.

Comment: Thank's for the answer! I was searching for a while now. I removed the default value and it works great now :)